# Using sizeof float in unity cg shader

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, sizeof, cg

I'm trying to write a shader for unity using cg, and I'd like to know what accuracy my floats have, but I can't figure out how to use the sizeof command.  When I attempt to use it, I get the error:

```
Shader error in 'Relativity/ColorShift': GLSL vertex shader: ERROR: 0:433: 'sizeof' : Reserved word.  at line 218
```

218 is the line that says "CGPROGRAM".

Can anyone tell me if there's either a standard size using the arbvp1/arbfp1 profile for a float or how to use the sizeof command?

Answer (score 0):

the standard size will be (hopefully) written here: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/arbvp1.html, in the Data Types section (currently says "to-be-written")

meanwhile, you can try to assume that, as per Cg specs, float is 32 bit.

as for sizeof, it's a reserved word, but not implemented, at least not as a library function

in Cg runtime (but not in Unity) you could use cgGetParameterResourceSize()...